# Node.js server on raspberry Pi 3B unreachable from React Native app after few succesful iterations

Tags: node.js, react-native, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a simple React Native which sends to a Node.js server hosted on a Raspberry Pi3B an order to switch on or off a led.

React Native code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
        super(props);};

  led(couleur){
    fetch('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX/switchOnOff', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },body: JSON.stringify({'couleur': couleur}),
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>

        <View style={styles.bleu}>
            <Button title="Bleu" color='blue' onPress={() => this.led('bleu')}/>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }

 }
```

On the Raspberry, I have the following for my Node.js server :

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio,
led14 = new Gpio(14, 'out');     

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var allumer = false;

app.post('/switchOnOff', function (req, res) {
coul = req.body['couleur'];
console.log('working!');

var val = !allumer ? 1 : 0;

if (coul == 'bleu'){
led14.writeSync(val);}


led14.watch((err, mess) => {
    if (err){throw err }})
allumer = !allumer;
}
   });


var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

strangely, this is working 5 times in a row (I get in the server console "working!" printed five times, and the led is toggled on/off).

But then I get the following error :

[image]

From then, I'm not able to send data to the server using the React Native app...

Has anyone any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to send requests via Postman or some other http client and get a successful response? (Is the issue with React-native or your rasp. pi?)

Comment: Yes I am : I can send data from the React-Native to the Raspberry Pi, but only five times in a row. After it stops, and I have to refresh the app on the smartphone to be able to send data again. So I guess the issue is with React-Native, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: You should use another application to confirm that.  I see "Network request failed" and "onerror" and it makes me think that you're not handling a network request failure on the react-native side (think `.on('error',callbackfn)` but also that something is happening on the rasp-pi side (max connections reached?)  the failure note is coming from `whatwg-fetch` which would make me think it's from your `fetch` call's error not being handled. (maybe react-native requires differently handling then .catch ?) or that you cannot use `console.error` --- maybe try `console.log` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I got it :

the error was coming from the server side: I was missing one line of code `res.end()`
which ends each request

Modified server side code :

```
app.post('/switchOnOff', function (req, res) {
   coul = req.body['couleur'];
   console.log('working!');

   var val = !allumer ? 1 : 0;

   if (coul == 'bleu'){
       led14.writeSync(val);}


   led14.watch((err, mess) => {
      if (err){throw err }})
   allumer = !allumer;
   }

  //#########solving line##########
  res.end
  });
```